# get values from nested JSON array

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

How can I get individual values from this JSON? For example the SSN? Also, some items are arrays that can hold multiples (addresses, phones). What is the best way to parse this? I have tried with JArray.Parse(data), but still can't "find" the individual items. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
[{
    "firstName": "test",
    "middleName": "test",
    "lastName": "test"
},
{
    "addresses":
    [{
        "street": "test",
        "city": "test",
        "state": "test",
        "zip": "test"
    }]
},
{
    "DOB": ""
},
{
    "SSN": "123123123"
},
{
    "occupation": "test",
    "typeOfOccupation": "test"
},
{
    "phones":
    [{
        "phone": "",
        "type": ""
    }]
},
{
    "Email": ""
},
{
    "typeOfId": "",
    "idNumber": "",
    "expirationDate": ""
}]
```

Comment: Show your actual code. Parsing JSON in c# is a topic covered repeatedly and extensively.

Comment: This could be helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079116/getting-data-from-a-deeply-nested-json-object

Answer (score 0):

You said you used `JArray.Parse` but are you using it as a `dynamic`? [Check Query JSON with dynamic](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm) with [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
var json = "[{ \"firstName\": \"test\", \"middleName\": \"test\", \"lastName\": \"test\" }, { \"addresses\": [{ \"street\": \"test\", \"city\": \"test\", \"state\": \"test\", \"zip\": \"test\" }] }, { \"DOB\": \"\" }, { \"SSN\": \"123123123\" }, { \"occupation\": \"test\", \"typeOfOccupation\": \"test\" }, { \"phones\": [{ \"phone\": \"\", \"type\": \"\" }] }, { \"Email\": \"\" }, { \"typeOfId\": \"\", \"idNumber\": \"\", \"expirationDate\": \"\" }]";
var data = JArray.Parse(json);
JToken ssn = data.SelectToken("$..SSN")
if(ssn!=null){
    Console.WriteLine(ssn.Value<string>());
}
```

Working [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MkTY0H).

Comment: Thank you Matias. Is there any way to do this without knowing the position of the data? for example, sometimes the SSN might appear before the DOB (or there may be some other change to the structure)? Can I "find" the SSN anyways?

Comment: Since it's an Array and not an Object, no, don't think you can unless you loop in the entire array looking for said attribute, not really efficient.

Comment: this seems to work:                                                                          dynamic arr = JArray.Parse(data); 
 JToken ssn = arr.SelectToken("$..SSN");  do you see any problem with it?

Comment: Interesting, never tried the dots on the SelectToken method, updated the fiddle with the working code using `Value<string>()`