# c# get nested data value from json object

Tags: c#

Hello I have one json object  which includes nested data such as below

```
{
"key1":"test",
"key2":{
  "key3" :"test2"
 }
}
```

and I have one List like below

```
  List<string> listkeys=  new List<string>() {"key1","key2.key3" }
```

I want to enter loop of listkeys and get value from json object dynamically.

```
foreach (int element in listkeys)
{
    //how can I get value with element
}
```

I couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to make a custom model, or use something like JObject.Parse?

Comment: Json.NET or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079116/getting-data-from-a-deeply-nested-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Json.NET I recommend `SelectToken`. Please see [Querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).

```
foreach (var element in listkeys) // btw. var/string, not `int`
{
    JToken j = o.SelectToken($"$..{element}");
}
```

Comment: That is what I exactly look for. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @tymtam Is it possible to change the value of the received `JToken`?

Comment: In what sense change it? Maybe you could ask a separate question with an example showing what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [JSON.net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) to parse Json, you can do it this way.

```
foreach (string element in listkeys) // Quick fix, listkeys stores strings, not integers
{
    string[] keys = element.split("."); // "key2.key3" => ["key2", "key3"]
    JObject obj = <jsonObject>;
    foreach (string key in keys) // When key = "key2", obj = <jsonObject>["key2"], when key = "key3", obj = <jsonObject>["key2"]["key3"]
        obj = obj[key];
    <do something with obj>
}
```

Just replace the *jsonObject* with the Json object of yours.